# How to determine if web services deployed correctly on websphere application server?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, websphere, ear

hey guys I'm a newbie at IBM websphere Application server and have a general question !

I'm trying to deploy an ear file which only has some ejb jar files(no wars) which cantains **@webservice** annotations to expose JAX-WS web services.

the ear structure is base on J2EE standard and it works on weblogic and glassfish as well, but when I deploy my ear on **websphere 9.0 application server** and try to test it's web services by **SOAPUI tool**  I get 404 error repeatedly.

unfortunately I can't see my web services list in admin console or even their wsdl files.

Although my ear deployed successfuly and has started status at websphere application server console. 
I dont know how to test it :( does it need any precondition?

these are my tested urls on address bar to see wsdl files but couldn't

http://localhost:9080/my-app-display-name/my-web-service-name.wsdl

http://localhost:8880/my-app-display-name/my-web-service-name.wsdl

Comment: Start debugging by having a look at the server logs, WAS_PROFILE_HOME\logs\server1\SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log particularly during the time period when you're deploying the application.  Also look at any FFDC in WAS_PROFILE_HOME\logs\ffdc

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23752121/5215049. This seems to be your case.
Enabling trace for JAX-WS should help you debug this issue.

Refer: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/capturing_web_service_jax_ws_messages_in_websphere?lang=en for specific instructions on enabling JAX-WS trace logs in Websphere

Refer : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_tracewbscomp.html for detailed instructions for tracing webservices in general.